# how to expose list of objects with dbus

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I would like my dbus interface to have paths like this:

- /org/fusegui/sites/example.com
- /org/fusegui/sites/www.kernel.org

Each of the above is an object with the same methods: host(), name(), timeout(), etcetera.

How would I achieve above in python? For example if I would have a list filled with those site objects. How would I loop them and add the, to the dbus service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I crafted this together:

```
import gtk
import dbus
import dbus.service
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

class MyDBUSObject(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('org.fusegui', bus=dbus.SessionBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, path)

    @dbus.service.method('org.fusegui.site')
    def hello(self):
        return "Hello,World!"

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
for i in range(0, 50):
    MyDBUSObject('/org/fusegui/sites/%i' % i)
gtk.main()
```

It seems to be exporting the objects like I wanted it. I don't know if it's the right way™ to do it.

Answer (score 0):

dbus-python: [Exporting Objects](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#exporting-objects)